# How do I retrieve the 'Created By' field using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am using the following function to retrieve data from a list using the SP REST API.

All seems to work except for the 'Created By' field.

How can I retrieve data from the 'Created By' field? I get 'undefined' for the 'Created By' field. Thank you.

```
function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://.../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('NET%20Support%20Tracker')/items?$top=1000",
            headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
        }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            const items = data.data.d.results;
            console.log(items);
            console.log('Title: ' + items[0].Title);
            console.log('Issue: ' + items[0].Issue);
            console.log('Created by: ' + items[0]['Created By']);

    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to expand the user fields while retrieving form SharePoint list items
you API should have `$select=Author/Name&$expand=Author` Author is internal name of Created By field.

Note: When you use expand it is mandatory that you specify fields that you want to retrieve in `$select`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) of created by column which is "Author".

Because it is a person field you also have to expand it. See this [link](https://www.kofrimpong.com/sharepoint-person-or-group-field-properties/) list all expandable properties.

You can get the internal field name by using the following command `_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<list name>')/fields?$filter=Title eq 'Your Field'`. I would also recommend to always use *select* to define the fields you want to return.

Your call should be something like this:

```
https://.../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('NET%20Support%20Tracker')/items?$top=1000&$select=Title,Issue,Author/Name&$expand=Author
```